# 3-dynamic-width-column layout without tables

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to achieve the following layout without success:

[image]

The requirements are:

1. All three columns, red, green and blue, must have dynamic widths, i.e. their width must change according to their content.
2. The gray container must be centered and its width must be dynamic as well, depending on the content of the three columns.
3. The HTML code for the green column must be before the other two columns in the source code.

This is easy as cake using tables, except for the third requirement, but I just can't manage to do it using DIVs and CSS.
The closest thing I've found is "[The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout (Percentage widths)](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm)", but it has percentage widths, which doesn't suit what I need.

Comment: I'm assuming you're putting the centre column first for SEO reasons. Really, you don't need to do this - search engines are clever enough to work out what to crawl. Can you put what you currently have in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: google free css templates 3 column layout, there are quite a few which do exactly what you want, you can reverse engineer the base framework from that.

Comment: @JamWaffles, it's not for SEO reasons, it's for AdSense reasons. AdSense ads that are first in the source code are the ones that pay more. I want the highest paying ad in the center column. What I'm currently using is the layout from that link I posted.

Comment: @Serdalis, I did a search already and the best I could find was that one in the link.

Comment: Why does the percentage width layout from MJT not suit your needs? The col widths are flexible.

Comment: @marissa.c, I need the column widths to be dynamic so that whatever content I put in there the columns are set to be just as wide as they need to be. What I need is just what you get using a centered 3-column table. But I want to avoid using tables if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily doable nowadays with flex-box.
Here you go. All your 3 requirements are met without a single use of the properties `width` or `height`. All containers adjust to their content.

```css
body {text-align:center; font: 16px arial}
wrap {display: inline-flex;  flex-direction: column; background: lightgrey;}
header {margin-bottom: 10px; background: white; }
footer {margin-top: 10px; background: white}
content {display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse}
ctnr {display: flex;}
centerCol {margin: 0 10px; background: green}
rightCol {background: blue}
leftCol {background: red}
[pad] {padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<wrap pad>
<header pad>Header</header>
<content>
<ctnr>
<centerCol pad><br><br><br>Center column<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></centerCol>
<rightCol pad>Right</rightCol>
</ctnr>
<ctnr>
<leftCol pad>Left</leftCol>
</ctnr>
</content>
<footer pad>Footer</footer>
</wrap>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found how to put the the center column first in the code

http://jsfiddle.net/gamepreneur/bj6bU/

html

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="right-float">
        <div class="green">
            green
        </div>
        <div class="blue">
            blue
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
        red
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.right-float {
    float:right
}
.green {
    float:left;
}
.blue {
    float:right
}
.red {
    float:left;
}
```

I'm just not sure how to do the rest... plus it's 12:40pm (at the time that i am writing this)